# Why do I get a compilation error when using the emplace method for unordered_map?

Tags: c++, hashtable, unordered-map

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

....
....
unordered_map<char, int> hashtable;
string str = "hello";
char lower = tolower(str[0]);
hashtable.emplace(lower, 1);
....
```

returns the following compilation errors:

```
1   error C2780: 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> std::_Hash<_Traits>::emplace(_Valty &&)' : expects 1 arguments - 2 provided  
2   IntelliSense: no instance of function template "std::tr1::unordered_map<_Kty, _Ty, _Hasher, _Keyeq, _Alloc>::emplace [with _Kty=char, _Ty=int, _Hasher=std::hash<char>, _Keyeq=std::equal_to<char>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const char, int>>]" matches the argument list
```

Comment: If it's VS < 2013 then it does not support `emplace` with more than one argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an old version of Visual C++ which did not correctly support `emplace`. Probably Visual C++ 2010.

As the [Visual C++ Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx) once said:

> As required by C++11, we've implemented
>   emplace()/emplace_front()/emplace_back()/emplace_hint()/emplace_after()
>   in all containers for "arbitrary" numbers of arguments (see below).
>
> (...)
>
> **VC10 supported emplacement from 1 argument, which was not
>   especially useful.**

The best solution would be to upgrade to the latest version of the compiler.

Comment: Oh, got it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Following some extensions which could fix your issue

```
#include <utility> // for std::pair
std::unordered_map<char, int> hashtable;
char lower = 'A';
hashtable.emplace(std::pair<char, int>(lower, 1));
```

If your pasted code compiles seems to be depending on the underlying compiler. Handling to emplace a std::pair works for e.g. c++11--according to the spec (e.g. [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/emplace/)) your code snippet should work with c++14.